# Is it possible dynamically to create a MediaWiki list of pages based on template date?

Tags: templates, wiki, mediawiki

We have a MediaWiki wiki in which we make extensive use of templates. These templates often include a future date.  For example, when a page should be deleted, we use a deletion template with a date one week in the future.  (This then produces a message on the page showing that the page will be subject to deletion at that date.)

Is there an easy way of dynamically creating a list of pages based on that date?  Basically we want to list all the pages that may be deleted, for easy administration.

**Note** the accepted answer below requires you to read the comments to see all possible solutions (not yet worked out in detail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a category into your template, then it will be added to any pages that the template is included on.

Comment: You mean a date specific category?

Comment: @Adrian - I mean, if we create a new category for each date, that kind of defeats the object. We want to add the date only in one place.

Comment: If you don't want a category for each date then why don't you make a general "To Delete" category.

If you want a category for each date, just make your template {template|day|month|year}
Then in your template  <includeonly> put [[{{day}}-{{month}}-{{year}}]] or something like that.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. What you're saying is that, if we want to use a date, we are obliged to use a category as the only dynamic way of displaying the information, right? I was wondering if there was a way without a category, because categories imply overhead (creation, putting into a parent category).

Comment: Even if you don't use a date, I don't know any other dynamic way of displaying the information other than using a category. You could make your own special page, and some new tag that lists the things you want, but isn't a category.

Answer (score 2):

[DPL (dynamic page list)](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28Wikimedia%29) can draw information from pages from templates.  Same with [SMW](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/).